# Avoid URL transform with PHP

Tags: php

I´m having issues with a link that is created in a php controller (Yii Framework). The link must be like this: `https://example.com/track/?id=HDkuY0je9d` (`HDkuY0je9d` is a tracking code) but when the view is rendered  i get `https://example.com/track/?id=h-dku-y0je9d`
PHP is adding dash delimited automatically.

```
$trackcode = $val['tracking'];
$url_tracking =  Yii::app()->createUrl("/track/?id=".$trackcode);
$tracking = '<a href="'.$url_tracking.'" target="_blank" class="btn btn-success btn-sm">Tracking</a>';
```

Comment: Please show the code used that results in the problem.

Answer (score 4):

If you are using Yii2 in this, it has helper class for create url and url must have been

```
$url_tracking =  yii\helpers\Url::to(['/track','id'=>$trackcode]);
```

and for generate link

```
<?=\yii\helpers\Html::a('Link description',$url_tracking,['target'=>'_blank']) ?>
```

Answer (score 2):

Thanks, I solved changing the way i get app url. Changed

```
$url_tracking =  Yii::app()->createUrl("/track/?id=".$trackcode);
```

for

```
$url_tracking = websiteUrl()."/track/?id=".$trackcode;
```